# Unity: Strange Camera Offset for multi-monitors at different resolutions

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, offset, monitor, display

I am creating a game (it's actually more of an application/useful software than a game) which needs to be run on multiple monitors, where **all monitors are** potentially **different resolutions**.

[image: Strange rendering crop indicated by grey area]

In the example below, you can see the primary monitor (far left) rendering a full screen camera view, just as it should. There are two other cameras set to render to monitor 2 and 3. These are activated with `Display.displays [1].Activate (1600, 900, 50);` (so as to set their resolutions to 1600x900).

The issue is that Unity appears to be offsetting the camera rendering so that it does not originate from the top left of the screen, but rather some way down the window. The ***grey area*** shows the area where the image is missing.

When running in the editor, the cameras render each window perfectly with no strange offsetting/cropping.

What do I need to do in order to get the standalone output to render the correct, uncropped/offset image in each of the windows, please?

---

If I make the resolution of all monitors the same, it renders exactly as it should do:
[image: All monitor resolutions set to the same resolution - 1600x900]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annoyingly, this seems to be a bug with Unity version 5.3.x. It seems to be fixed in 5.4.x [[See Bug Report Here]](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/windows-multidisplay-the-second-screen-in-the-multi-display-mode-gets-weird-offset-when-using-different-screen-resolutions) (I have downloaded the beta and tested it - I can confirm this to be true!). However, 5.4.x is currently in beta and you can only access it if you have Unity Pro.